# hibernate.connection.provider_class exception:Could not instantiate connection provider

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I hibernate version i am using is 3.2.5

This is how my cfg.xml file looks like, i am using hibernate.connection.provider_class to retrieve the connection:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.jdbc.ConnProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>    
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

This is the ConnProvider class:

```
    package com.jdbc;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProvider;

/**
 *
 * @author gOMzY
 */
class ConnProvider implements ConnectionProvider {

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        try{

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection("<url>","<username>","<pwd>");
            System.out.println("Connected!!!");
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
        return conn;
    }

    @Override
    public void closeConnection(Connection cnctn) throws SQLException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws HibernateException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Properties prprts) throws HibernateException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

The exception i am getting:

SEVERE: Could not instantiate connection provider
    java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory can not access a member of class com.infy.jdbc.ConnProvider with modifiers ""
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:414)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:62)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
        at com.infy.jdbc.HibernateStartup.main(HibernateStartup.java:19)

Please suggest how to solve this issue.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Note that your connection provider has default visibility, perhaps it should be public instead:

```
public ConnProvider implements ConnectionProvider { ... }
```

Comment: got this exception:INFO: Initializing connection provider: com.infy.jdbc.ConnProvider
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
 at com.infy.jdbc.ConnProvider.configure(ConnProvider.java:47)
 at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
 at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:414)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:62.

Comment: This is my main method:SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("trial.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
   session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   tx = session.beginTransaction();
   Login login = (Login)session.get(Login.class, new String("Gautam"));
   System.out.println("Name: " + login.getName());
   System.out.println("Age: " + login.getAge());
   tx.commit();

Comment: @user182944: `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown by your code.

Comment: yes, please provide some inputs regd. how to solve this issue.